# google calendar api service.calendars().clear(calendarId=calenderID).execute() returns Invalid Value

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

When executing service.calendars().clear(calendarId=calenderID).execute() on a SECONDARY calendar, one gets the following answer:

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXc%40group.calendar.google.com/clear? returned "Invalid Value">

The documentation in https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear
seems to evolve on 'primary' calendars, though it is not consistent over the programming languages, in ruby the example quotes 'calendarId', while in the other programming languages, 'primary' is used.

How are events on a secondary calendar deleted?

Answer (score 2):

For deleting an event in a secondary calendar, you must use the [Events: delete](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete?apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22secondary-calendar-id%22%2C%22eventId%22%3A%22secondary-calendar-event-id%22%7D) endpoint. A Python example would look like this:

```python
service.events().delete(calendarId='secondary-calendar-id', eventId='secondary-calendar-event-id').execute()
```

If you want to get a list of all the calendars you have and in that way get their ids, you can use the [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) endpoint. A Python example would look like this:

```python
page_token = None
while True:
  calendar_list = service.calendarList().list(pageToken=page_token).execute()
  for calendar_list_entry in calendar_list['items']:
    print calendar_list_entry['summary']
  page_token = calendar_list.get('nextPageToken')
  if not page_token:
    break
```